# Get CallerId (Username) from incoming call Linphone - Swift

Tags: swift, sip, voip, linphone, linphone-sdk

I've just found a simple way to get the some CallLogs (CallerID, Username, To, From, Call duration, Date, Status, ...) from the new Linphone library for swift (SDK 5.0).

I just want to share it with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [Linphone's documentation](https://download.linphone.org/snapshots/docs/liblinphone/5.0/swift/Classes/CallLog.html#/s:10linphonesw7CallLogC9startDateSivp), and some testings, I found at least 2 simple ways to retrieve the CallLog and read it:

**1. Using `CoreDelegateStub`**

```
CoreDelegateStub( onCallStateChanged: { (core: Core, call: Call, state: Call.State, message: String) in
```

So, you can use the `call` attribute to get the CallerID(Username) for example, like that:

```
call.callLog?.fromAddress?.username
```

Remember, the callLog object contains a ton of parameters that you can find in the documentation

**2. Using `Core` from Linphone wrapper**

```
var mCore: Core!
self.mCore.callLogs
```

In that way, you can retrieve all your call logs in an array, so you will need to choose an item and get the attributes from it like I've shown above.

```
self.mCore.callLogs[0].fromAddress?.username
```